# Is there an online directory of algorithms and their implementations in different languages?

Tags: algorithm, programming-languages

For example, on such a site, you could look up Quicksort and get a listing of (user-contributed) Quicksort implementations in C, Java, OCaml, etc. I believe this service already exists but I can't find it.

Comment: wikipedia itself? e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Welcome_to_Rosetta_Code ?

Answer (score 1):

[pleac](http://pleac.sourceforge.net/) contains a lot of solutions to common programming problems, mainly  for so called scipting languages.

Answer (score 1):

[Nist](http://xlinux.nist.gov/dads/), Dictionary of Algorithms and Data Structures

Answer (score 0):

In a different vein, http://benchmarksgame.alioth.debian.org/ contains lots of highly optimized implementations of many tasks in many languages, a number of which happen to be closely tied to well-known algorithms.